# Macedonian Entry Visas

Tags: visas, schengen, macedonia

I've a Schengen visa valid till 11th of August, issued from a German Embassy, I would like to know if this would prevent me entry to Macedonia as my conference finished at 9th of August

Because I read that I should have 5 days in the visa beyond my intended day of leaving

And what should I do ?

Comment: I would suspect not if you remain within the Schengen area, there are no border controls between states. Are you leaving from Macedonia or Germany ?

Comment: i will go from germany to macedonia then leave back to jordan from there 

that's what i read on the website of ministry of Macedonian foreign affairs 

3. Third countries with multiple entry short stay Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of Macedonia.
may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia

Comment: I think this applies if Macedonia is your first port of entry into Schengen

Comment: @Blackbird57 Macedonia is not part of the Schengen area, although they do allow people holding a Schengen visa to enter without a Macedonian visa (but only for 15 days rather than the usual 90).

Comment: thank you :) 
but i am afraid from this 
 Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of Macedonia.
since i have only 2 days left when i will leave

Answer (score 2):

Well you've read right.  According to [Ministry of Foreign](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php/en/for-foreign-nationals/information-on-visa-entry-to-the-republic-of-macedonia/entry-in-the-republic-of-macedonia-for-schengen-visa-holders) affairs you  will need to have your visa valid at least 5 days past your leaving Macedonia and it has to be Multiple Entry.

> **3. Third countries with multiple entry short stay Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of Macedonia.**
>
> may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.

So you have 2 options:

1. Get another Multi-Entry Schengen Visa starting August 12th.
2. Get a Macedonia Visa.

I would probably go for the latter.  But it's up to you.

Comment: (+1) The former would not be possible without a very good purpose (upcoming or continuing trip) or lying about it. Schengen countries don't issue visas to facilitate entry in non-Schengen countries.